# Postfix Configuration on Ubuntu 15.04 VPS

Tags: postfix, sendmail

this is my first time posting here so I apologize if anything (or everything) is out of line.

Basically just have a Wordpress site I'm hosting on a VPS running Ubuntu 15.04, MariaDB, nginx. I have postfix installed and I'm really only getting anything email related setup just so I can send the activation letters for user sign up.

I setup mail.mydomain.com as an MX Entry, I installed postfix and configured it, edited the php.ini file to reflect postfix. So where I'm at now is I can get an email to send out in terminal using `/usr/sbin/sendmail -t` but if I try to send something out in Wordpress, like try for a registration for example, I find this in the mail.log:

```
fatal: Recipient addresses must be specified on the command line or via the -t option
```

I tried to research this online and most of the answers I found pointed to the sendmail path not being correct in the php.ini file.

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

That's from my `php.ini` file and from everything I can find that's how it's suppose to be setup.

Thank you for anyone that is able to help, I'm pretty new at trying to manage my own server vs taking a managed solution so I apologize if this is out of line or a dumb question.

Comment: Honestly, just look at using transactional email services like MailChimp instead, they're installable in a few clicks as a Wordpress plugin and require no maintenance, as opposed to installing a Postfix server you're clearly not experienced enough to maintain.

Comment: I'm happy to give it a shot, I'll go ahead and set that up this evening and see how it works. I would still like to end up finding the answer though, because hey I have to get the experience somewhere, even if I don't have it now.

Comment: Check whether your `sendmail` exists at that path by running `which sendmail`, make sure the sendmail path line is uncommented in php.ini and that you restarted PHP-FPM (or Apache) to reload the modified php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve similar error, so maybe this helps someone.
Check this link for very similar manual in my [BLOG](http://www.note.id.lv/2016/12/moodle-smtp-error-postfix-exchange.html).

1. Check errors in log file.
   sudo tail -n10 /var/log/mail.log

   - Search for "**fatal: Recipient addresses**"
   - If you see this error, then this manual may help you.
2. Open **php.ini** for editing on server.

   - Make sure, you edit correct php.ini!!
3. Check if smtp is uncommented :

   ```
           [mail function]
           SMTP = localhost
           smtp_port = 25
   ```
4. Open for editing file : **/etc/postfix/main.cf**
5. In section relayhost, add your MS Exchange server name :
               **relayhost = exchange.domain.lv**
6. Add www-data user to mail group :
               **sudo adduser www-data mail**
7. Check if /etc/hosts has correct values.

   - Your server name for example.
8. Restart apache2, php5-fpm